# Scaling Selection Symbols with Reference Scale using ArcGIS Engine?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, arcgis-engine, scale

With an ArcGIS Engine application, I am trying to figure out how to have the Selected Symbols scale with reference scale when selected using ArcObjects.  They are currently not scaling correctly in ArcGIS Engine.  Example, I select a stylized point that is using the "with this color" under layer properties (not the generic "with this symbol" option).

You can set this option in ArcMap via the "Select Options" dialog, and by checking "Scale selection symbols when a reference scale is set".  Saving the map does not persist this setting when an MXD is opened in the ArcGIS Engine application.  So in the example above, the stylized point will be colored, but it is only true to scale at the given reference scale when selected.

I have combed a lot of articles and found the various Selection interfaces (threshold tolerances, record counts, layer saving colors, etc.)

Where can I find this interface that controls the selection scaling (using ArcGIS Engine)?

I am about to go a graphics layer route, but I would prefer not to if the "easy" answer is out there.